# How to start multiple processes in Bash

Tags: bash

I want to start 100 processes in `bash`, but the `for` statement doesn't seems to like the `&` symbol and I'm getting a syntax error, here is what I have so far:

```
echo "Spawning 100 processes"
for i in {1..100}
do
    ./my_script.py &
done
```

**EDIT:** I was copypasting this code, that's why the `&` char was illegal.

Comment: This shouldn't be causing a syntax error. Perhaps you can paste the whole script and my_script.py and we can see if it might be something else?

Comment: That looks fine to me...

Comment: What the error?. Its working for me. Which version of bash?.

Comment: You should show *the* syntax error rather than a vague reference to *a* syntax error.

Comment: I'm with @Rafe. I have a suspicion that the syntax error is in `my_script.py` itself

Comment: Shyly saying "hi"... editing at the moment the problem was that I was copy pasting the code :-)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
echo "Spawning 100 processes"
for i in {1..100} ;
do
    ( ./my_script & )
; done
```

Comment: What?  The semi-colons are redundant, and I'm not sure what the effect of parenthesising here would be, given that the OP's code snippet is syntactically valid.

Comment: The nice thing writing it that way is, that you can copy'n'paste the pice of code into the interactive shell, run it there -- doesn't work without putting the my_script call into a expression list and the semicolons. It may be redundant, but has it's reasons. I suspected the OP may have tried this in the interactive mode of the shell, given that he didn't supplied a script with a #!

Comment: Enclosing the call between ( ) made the cut!! 
Thanks,

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: The effect of the parentheses is, that the list inside the parenthesis is executed in their own sub-shell, and backgrounding happens inside that sub-shell.

Comment: What's the point of doing the backgrounding inside a subshell?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, in docker which extends "FROM python:3.7.2-slim" I want to call a shell script, which will start other processes. In that shell script,I have too use semicolons; otherwise, there will be errors.

Comment: @Yan Khonski It doesn't matter if you're in docker: the Bash shell is the Bash shell. Now different versions of the shell may have differences- but I doubt the existence of semicolons is one of those things. In bash, semicolons and newlines are both delimiters. That's just how it works.

Comment: @datenwolf one can run this in an interactive Bash shell: `for i in {1..100}; do eval 'echo mypid $BASHPID' & done` . No  additional parens are necessary. Do you have any specific reasons? I don't see any advantage to the parens. They will run the myscript in a subshell, true, but then so will the ampersand, as the Bash man page sasy and as my code shows. I have a mind to edit your answer, but I would be very interested to see how you're correct. It seems to defy my understanding of Bash and my reading of the man pages.

Comment: @MikeS: The parentheses are not just about the backgrounding. They also effect things as filedescriptor redirection scope. With a subshell redirections therein (not shown in the answer) are localized to that. If you read up the comments before yours, having the parentheses were the key to make it work for other people. Please don't change it.

Comment: @datenwolf You may be right about filedescriptor redirection scope, but then that's not included in your answer's code and you say above that "(the code) ...doesn't work without putting the my_script call into a expression list and the semicolons." But the `./my_script` call as shown  does work in an interactive shell without parens, and the semicolons are unnecessary if you have newlines, which your code does. Could you demonstrate what you mean? I think in your answer you're expanding the scope of what the OP needed.

Answer (score 20):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
echo "Spawning 100 processes"
parallel -j0 ./my_script.py ::: {1..100}
```

Or to avoid the argument 1 through 100:

```
parallel -j0 -N0 ./my_script.py ::: {1..100}
```

Without -j0 it will spawn one process per CPU thread.

Watch the intro videos for more details: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Comment: this should be the best answer!

Comment: Didn't realize you were the author of the program

Comment: Won't this also pass each of 1 to 100 as an argument to each instance of `./myscript.py`?  This may not be desirable.

Comment: @DerekMahar This can be avoided with -N0.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason I can think of why this wouldn't work is if you were really using some other shell, like `/bin/sh`.

Do you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your file? If yes, please change it to `#!/bin/bash -x` (to turn on tracing, or *xtrace* as it's called in the manual page) and paste the relevant output into your question, along with the exact syntax error that is occurring. If no, that might be your problem. ;-)

The other possibility I can think of is if you have `^M` characters (DOS line endings) in your file, which might result in errors such as the following (depending on which line they are on, if they are scattered around, or depending on if the script starts with a `#!` line):

```
-bash: ./myscript.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
'/myscript.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `do
```

[This page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/) has a nice perl snippet that can remove them, as follows (which I have modified slightly so it will work in the unlikely case that you have a stray `^M` in the middle of a line):

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r//g' myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your snippet is valid code.

Not sure if this is what you need ... but you can fork twice:

```
( ( /complete/path/my_script.py & ) & )
```

This will let your script run even if the shell it was launced from is destroyed.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 1):

In this example we have 2 parallel processes, based on different arguments (numbers)

`my_array=(1 2 3 4) ; printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}" | parallel -j 2 "echo {} &"`

You can replace `my_array`  by something that generates output for the `echo` command (e.g: `find *tif  -printf "%f\n"`)

If can also used `nohup` to prevent the processed to be terminated when you close a ssh session:
`nohup sh -c 'find *tif  -printf "%f\n" | parallel -j 2 echo {}' &`