# Start multiple processes in Bash and time how long they take

Tags: bash, process

How do I start multiple processes in bash and time how long they take?
From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5238103/5415895) I know how to start multiple processes in a bash script but using `time script.sh` doesn't work because the processes spawned end after the script ends.
I tried using `wait` but that didn't change anything.
Here is the script in its entirety:

```
for i in `seq $1`
do
    ( ./client & )
done
wait # This doesn't seem to change anything
```

I'm trying to get the total time for all the processes to finish and not the time for each process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the parentheses around `client` invocation?  That's going to run the command in a subshell.  Since the background job isn't in the top level shell, that's why the wait is ineffective (there's no jobs in *this* shell to wait for).

Then you can add `time` back inside the `for` loop and it should work.